# How can I put drop down in all row data?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I made dummy data in the database, displaying name, last name and the instrument they borrowed, beside it is a drop down for the list of available instruments if they want to change their borrowed instruments but I can't put drop down to other row data, I did only for the first row of data, I want all row data to have drop down, How?
[database](https://github.com/patrickesguerra/sql)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","borrow");
$q="SELECT students.studentid,students.studfname,students.studlname,instruments.instrumentname from students INNER JOIN student_instrument ON students.studentid=student_instrument.id INNER JOIN instruments ON student_instrument.checkoutdate=instruments.dateacquired";

$t="SELECT instrumentname from instruments where dateacquired='avail'";
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);
$e=mysqli_query($con,$t);

while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    echo '<form method="post">'; 
    $id=$result['studentid'];
    $studfname=$result['studfname'];
    $studlname=$result['studlname'];
    $instrumentname=$result['instrumentname'];
    echo $studfname." ".$studlname." ".$instrumentname." ";
    echo '<select name="inst">';
    while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($e)){
    $avail=$f['instrumentname'];
    echo '<option>'.$avail.'</option>';
    }
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value='.$id.'>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>';
    echo '</form>';
}
 ?>

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $inst=$_POST['inst'];
     $p="UPDATE instruments SET instrumentname='$inst' WHERE id='$id'";
     $q=mysqli_query($con,$p);
     if($q){
         header('location:borrow.php');
     }
 }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i guess you have to change you query to:

```
        $t="SELECT instrumentname from instruments where dateacquired='avail'";

    $e=mysqli_query($con,$t);
    $select_options = '<select name="inst">';
        while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($e)){
            $select_options .= '<option value="' . $f['instrumentname'] . '">'. $f['instrumentname'] .'</option>';
            }
$select_options .= '</select>';

    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        echo '<form method="post" action="">'; 
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value='. $result['studentid'] 
        .'>';
        echo $result['studfname'] . " " . $result['studlname'] .
        " " . $result['instrumentname'] . " ";
        echo $select_options;
        echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
```

Try that hope it helps.

Comment: @dark phoenix i updated my answer, i guess the problem was in fetching a result. I think this way should works, better.

Comment: @dark phoenix i did a mistake in `select` grouping, try updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198787/discussion-between-dark-phoenix-and-serghei-leonenco).